# Get image length in iPhone sdk like photoruler

Tags: iphone

How to measure the image length after taking a picture in iPhone? Example: if I take a picture of FISH then how should I measure the fish actual height and width?

Any ideas or sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone is not equipped to do this. You would have to take into account the fish's angle, distance from the camera, and many other things.  In other words, you could potentially find the number of pixels the fish portion of the image occupied, but you wouldn't be able to accurately translate that into real world measurements without an in picture reference item with known measurements.  The closest you could come using just the device would be to tell them the print size of the fish image.

Answer (score 0):

In all photo rule style apps I've ever seen, you must have set some known distance on the plane you are measuring.

This I think is the only way of achieving what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting your ideas Nick Catwright.i will work out in that way.